# Function in SQL Server 2008 similar to GREATEST in mysql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to find the maximum value of multiple columns.

MySQL supports the [`GREATEST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) function but SQL Server doesn't.

Is there any function similar to this in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: Please also look at http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21542/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-get-the-minimum-of-multiple-columns-on-sql-ser

Answer (score 22):

Not in SQL Server 2008 but [`GREATEST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-greatest-transact-sql) and [`LEAST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-least-transact-sql) functions are now available for SQL Server 2022 and cloud versions of SQL Server

For previous versions you can use the fact a sub query can access the columns from the outer query so you can add a sub query Selecting the `max` from a union of those.

```
SELECT *, 
      (SELECT MAX(c) FROM (VALUES(number),(status)) T (c)) AS Greatest
FROM master..spt_values
```

Or for SQL Server 2000/2005

```
SELECT *, 
      (SELECT MAX(c) FROM 
                    (SELECT number AS c 
                     UNION ALL 
                     SELECT status) T) AS GreatestNumberOrStatus
FROM master..spt_values
```

Comment: +1, though it is less efficient than a bunch of `CASE` statements.

Comment: Agreed but it isn't catastrophically inefficient and easier to maintain if the number of columns is large.

Comment: "you can add a sub query UNION ALL ing the columns of interest as a derived table" -- could do the same using a CTE.

Comment: @oneday - I'm not sure how? The derived table only contains the values for the current row.

Comment: ++ for the VALUES() syntax for 2008

Comment: @Quassnoi: Can you provide an example with a bunch of `CASE` statements? I feel that the `CASE` statement size explodes with `O(2^n)` when `n` is the number of parameters to `GREATEST`...

Comment: +1000 for VALUES syntax! True, null-friendly, n-ary Greatest/Least() functionality! Agree with @Lukas about O(2ⁿ); plus, if nullable values, having to pick either a magic value for isnull (yuck), or expanding the syntax further with "OR val(n) is null".

Answer (score 5):

For this, I created a scalar function as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[MaxOrNull](@val1 int, @val2 int)
returns int
as
begin
    if @val1 >= @val2 RETURN @val1
    if @val1 < @val2 RETURN @val2

    RETURN NULL
end
```

It's the most elegant solution and can be used anywhere in your SQL code.

Comment: I'm not sure I've ever seen the words scalar function and elegant in the same sentence before! How would the OP use this to calculate `GREATEST(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6)` for example? Wouldn't it need a lot of permutations? Edit: Actually you could just nest the calls of course in this case where the permutations grow is the different scenario where you want to order across columns.

Comment: Well @Martin, sometimes it takes a shift of viewpoint to see elegance. Hard coding messy SQL all over the place like the verbose answer in the top answer ^^^ above is just crazy. You answered your second question. The same would hold true in C++ or C#.

Comment: A stretch for me to give you +1. But this is the approach I have used before SQL 2008, in preference over nested select-max-union. The function I normally use is more concise  `create function dbo.greater(@a int, @b int) returns int as begin return case when @a >= isnull(@b,@a) then @a else @b end end`

Comment: I like your CASE version. Very tidy. +1

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend the following solution:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN t.createdt < t.changedt THEN t.changedt ELSE t.created END) AS ChgDate
  FROM table t
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `TOP` instead or `MAX`.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[MaxOf]
    (
      @val1 INT =0,
      @val2 INT=0 ,
      @val3 INT =0,
      @val4 INT =0,
      @val5 INT =0,
      @val6 INT =0,
      @val7 INT =0,
      @val8 INT =0,
      @val9 INT =0,
      @val10 INT =0,
      @val11 INT =0,
      @val12 INT =0,
      @val13 INT =0,
      @val14 INT =0,
      @val15 INT =0,
      @val16 INT =0,
      @val17 INT =0,
      @val18 INT =0,
      @val19 INT =0,
      @val20 INT  =0)
      --OUTPUT 
     RETURNS INT  WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS  
   BEGIN
        DECLARE  @MAX AS INT ;
        SET @MAX=0
        IF isnull(@val1,0)> isnull(@MAX,0) SET @MAX=isnull(@val1,0) 
        IF isnull(@val2,0)> isnull(@MAX,0) SET @MAX=isnull(@val2,0) 
        IF isnull(@val3,0)> isnull(@MAX,0) SET @MAX=isnull(@val3,0) 
        IF isnull(@val4,0)> isnull(@MAX,0) SET @MAX=isnull(@val4,0) 
        IF isnull(@val5,0)> isnull(@MAX,0) SET @MAX=isnull(@val5,0) 
        IF isnull(@val6,0)> isnull(@MAX,0) SET @MAX=isnull(@val6,0) 
        IF isnull(@val7,0)> isnull(@MAX,0) SET @MAX=isnull(@val7,0) 
        IF isnull(@val8,0)> isnull(@MAX,0) SET @MAX=isnull(@val8,0) 
        IF isnull(@val9,0)> isnull(@MAX,0) SET @MAX=isnull(@val9,0) 
        IF isnull(@val10,0)> isnull(@MAX,0) SET @MAX=isnull(@val10,0) 
        IF isnull(@val11,0)> isnull(@MAX,0) SET @MAX=isnull(@val11,0) 
        IF isnull(@val12,0)> isnull(@MAX,0) SET @MAX=isnull(@val12,0) 
        IF isnull(@val13,0)> isnull(@MAX,0) SET @MAX=isnull(@val13,0) 
        IF isnull(@val14,0)> isnull(@MAX,0) SET @MAX=isnull(@val14,0) 
        IF isnull(@val15,0)> isnull(@MAX,0) SET @MAX=isnull(@val15,0) 
        IF isnull(@val16,0)> isnull(@MAX,0) SET @MAX=isnull(@val16,0) 
        IF isnull(@val17,0)> isnull(@MAX,0) SET @MAX=isnull(@val17,0) 
        IF isnull(@val18,0)> isnull(@MAX,0) SET @MAX=isnull(@val18,0) 
        IF isnull(@val19,0)> isnull(@MAX,0) SET @MAX=isnull(@val19,0) 
        IF isnull(@val20,0)> isnull(@MAX,0) SET @MAX=isnull(@val20,0) 

        RETURN @MAX ;
    END
```

and the call would be

```
SELECT dbo.MaxOf (2,3,4,0,0,0,0,200,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
```