# How to I modify this t-sql query to return the maximum value for different column names?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
        [Rate],
        [RateMon],
        [RateTue],
        [RateWed],
        [RateThu],
        [RateFri],
        [RateSat],
        [RateSun]
    FROM
        [Room]
    WHERE
        Id=@Id
```

Instead of returning all the columns, I just want to return `Rate` and the Maximum value between RateMon, RateTue, RateWed, RateThu, RateFri, RateSat, and RateSun, but I am having a hard time because the column names are different.

An example result return now is:

100, 400, 400, 400, 400, 600, 600, 600

where 100 is the Rate and the other values correspond to Mon - Sun, but I want to return just 100 and 600 in this case.

Comment: Please post example data and results. It's not clear what you are looking for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL MAX of multiple columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71022/sql-max-of-multiple-columns)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Function in SQL Server 2008 similar to GREATEST in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725823/function-in-sql-server-2008-similar-to-greatest-in-mysql)

Comment: I would not close this as an exact duplicate because Mikael Eriksson's answer provides something valuable that myself and others may have not known.

Comment: @Xaisoft - Did you click the duplicate link immediately above your comment?

Comment: Yes, I was going to use Lasse's answer, but I liked Mikaels better and  I did not know you could use VALUES outside an Insert like he did in his example.  This is something the other post does not have.

Comment: @Xaisoft - [er, it definitely has](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725823/function-in-sql-server-2008-similar-to-greatest-in-mysql/4725851#4725851)

Comment: @Michael, ah sorry about that, must have scanned too quickly.  Good point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT  [Rate],
        (SELECT MAX(T.[Rate])
         FROM (VALUES([RateMon]),
                     ([RateTue]),
                     ([RateWed]),
                     ([RateThu]),
                     ([RateFri]),
                     ([RateSat]),
                     ([RateSun])) AS T([Rate])
        ) AS MaxRate
FROM [Room]
WHERE Id=@Id
```

Comment: Best answer because it is most succint.

Comment: Not sure if I should accept it though because you are from Sweden and I am part Norwegian :) Just kidding.

Comment: @Xaisoft - Well, I will not hold that against you :)

Comment: @Andomar - Yes, this is possible since SQL Server 2008. For previous version you can use `select ... union all` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something verbose like:

```
SELECT Rate,
  CASE 
    WHEN RateMon>=RateTue AND RateMon>=RateWed AND RateMon>=RateThu AND 
         RateMon>=RateFri AND RAteMon>=RateSat AND RateMon>=RateSun THEN RateMon
    WHEN RateTue>=RateMon AND RateTue>=RateWed AND RateTue>=RateThu AND 
         RateTue>=RateFri AND RateTue>=RateSat AND RateTue>=RateSun THEN RateTue
    WHEN RateWed>=RateMon AND RateWed>=RateTue AND RateWed>=RateThu AND 
         RateWed>=RateFri AND RateWed>=RateSat AND RateWed>=RateSun THEN RateWed
    WHEN RateThu>=RateMon AND RateThu>=RateTue AND RateThu>=RateWed AND 
         RateThu>=RateFri AND RateThu>=RateSat AND RateThu>=RateSun THEN RateThu
    WHEN RateFri>=RateMon AND RateFri>=RateTue AND RateFri>=RateWed AND 
         RateFri>=RateThu AND RateFri>=RateSat AND RateFri>=RateSun THEN RateFri
    WHEN RateSat>=RateMon AND RateSat>=RateTue AND RateSat>=RateWed AND 
         RateSat>=RateThu AND RateSat>=RateFri AND RateSat>=RateSun THEN RateSat
    WHEN RateSun>=RateMon AND RateSun>=RateTue AND RateSun>=RateWed AND 
         RateSun>=RateThu AND RateSun>=RateFri AND RateSun>=RateSat THEN RateSun
    END AS MaxRate 
FROM    
    [Room]    
WHERE    
    Id=@Id
```

A lot of typing, but that's one possible answer. You can also do the following, which is slightly less typing:

```
SELECT Rate, MAX(Rates.Rate) AS MaxRate
  FROM    
    [Room], 
      (SELECT RateMon AS Rate FROM [Room] WHERE Id=@Id UNION
       SELECT RateTue AS Rate FROM [Room] WHERE Id=@Id UNION
       SELECT RateWed AS Rate FROM [Room] WHERE Id=@Id UNION
       SELECT RateThu AS Rate FROM [Room] WHERE Id=@Id UNION
       SELECT RateFri AS Rate FROM [Room] WHERE Id=@Id UNION
       SELECT RateSat AS Rate FROM [Room] WHERE Id=@Id UNION
       SELECT RateSun AS Rate FROM [Room] WHERE Id=@Id)
     AS Rates
  WHERE    
    Id=@Id
```

Of course, the **correct solution** would be to normalize your database and make this moot, since a simple join and aggregate would be sufficient.

Comment: Wow that is huge.  Thanks, I will give it a shot.  You would think there would be something more simpler like given a set of columns, return the max value instead of having to to all this case logic.

Comment: There is on MySql (GREATEST) but not on SQL Server.

Comment: Yes, I read that on the other post. I wonder if it would be in a future releas of SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

You could unpivot the days with a `union` subquery:

```
select  Rate
,       max(DayRate)
from    (
        select ID, Rate, RateMon as DayRate from Room
        union all
        select ID, Rate, RateTue from Room
        union all
        select ID, Rate, RateWed from Room
        union all
        ....
        ) as SubQuery
where   ID = @ID
group by
        Rate
```