# Greatest of multiple values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server equivalent to Oracle LEAST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972051/sql-server-equivalent-to-oracle-least)
>   [Function in SQL Server 2008 similar to GREATEST in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725823/function-in-sql-server-2008-similar-to-greatest-in-mysql)

i am trying to find a SQL Server equivalent of oracle's "GREATEST" function.

something that would return the largest (in this case timestamp) from a list of values given

example: `greatest(timestamp1, temestamp2, timestamp3)`  would return the most current date.

is there something like this in SQL Server i can use?

Thanks!

Comment: There isn't a direct equivalent.  The linked question covers the same ground except for the `LEAST` function.

Comment: look at these two SO questions:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124417/is-there-a-max-function-in-sql-server-that-takes-two-values-like-math-max-in-ne  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71022/sql-max-of-multiple-columns

Comment: thank you! i will take a look at the links now

Comment: Lots of great information here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21542/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-get-the-minimum-of-multiple-columns-on-sql-ser

Comment: @helmus - thanks! the udf in one of your links did it!